# On semantic roles

Tags: semantics

What is the semantic role of the direct object in the below sentence? If I'm not mistaken, the answer is 'patient' (since 'He' is doing something [in this case, 'crossing'] to the river). However, I find it difficult to understand why this is so (if indeed it is at all), since, unlike 'hitting' or 'eating', for example, the river can't really undergo 'crossing' (if you see what I mean). Ideas?

> He crossed the river.

Comment: What is the range of the semantic roles you are to choose from? As for me, for the direct object, I'd choose from {the Affected, the Theme, the Experiencer, the Created Object, the Locative Object and Empty _it_}, so Locative Object seems to be the best choice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.